# Firebase data retrieval sporadically not returning

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a project with Firebase that involves users. There is a known Firebase bug where even after a user has been deleted from the Firebase Authentication section, the user is still able to access the app and still has read/write permissions to the database. I believe it has something to do with the token being stored by Firebase on the user's device.

As a work around to this, I have implemented a "user checkup" where my app will check to see if the userID of the logged in user exists in my real-time database. This way all i have to do is delete the userID node from the real-time database and that will cause this checkup to fail and thus log the user out permanently.

The problem i am having is that the call to `observeSingleEvent(of: .value...)` is sporadically not returning. By this i mean that sometimes it returns immediately as is expected, however sometimes it just doesn't return at all. For example yesterday morning it wasn't working at all. Yesterday afternoon and night it worked fine. Now today it is no longer working again. Code below...

```
     func checkDatabaseForFIRUser(withId: String, callback: @escaping (Bool)-> Void) {

        let fireUsersRef = fireRootRef.child("all-users").child(withId)

        fireUsersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot)-> Void in
            print("user check result -> \(snapshot)")
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print("SNAP EXISTS")
                callback(true)
            } else {
                print("SNAP NOT EXISTS")
                callback(false)
            }

        }, withCancel: {(error)-> Void in
            print("CANCEL BLOCK ERROR = \(error) and localized description = \(error.localizedDescription)")
        })

    }
```

I have also noticed that during the times when I am unable to retrieve data I am also unable to write anything to the database, it is as if nothing at all works. My Firebase Rules have been set to "Public" so anyone can read/write. And I have a working internet connection on my device

EDIT: everything works fine on Simulator. Issue is only occurring on the actual device

EDIT #2: This issue seems to have subsided, I haven't noticed it for at least a few weeks now

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why *callback(false)* or *callback(true)*. Also you state you are unable to write to the database. Does the data eventually get written? Are you including an error handler in your write function to see what the error is, if any?

Comment: callback to my ViewController with true or false depending on wether not not user exists, which then will determine what view the ViewController should present next. I have included an error handler but it is never called. I noticed that this has been working on the iPhone Simulator but not the actual device.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, did you figure out what is causing this?

Comment: No sorry, it just resolved itself and I haven't noticed it since I opened this issue

Answer (score 0):

I bet that by the time you are calling `observeSingleEvent`, you are log out, so probably that's why it is not returning anything.